# Segue pass image and display when the image view already have image

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I have 3 view controllers. The first one contains an `UIimageview`, 
 the second one is `customCameraViewController` and the third one is `previewController`. The application started at the first controller and there is a button to navigate to `customCameraViewController` after the user captures a photo, it will pass it to the `previewController`to decide to save or cancel the photo. If the user saves the photo it will use a segue to pass the `uiimage` back and display in the first controller.

**The problem is the uiimageView already set a "default profile photo"
How can this problem solve when the user opens the application. It displays the "default photo" and then capture photo and pass it back to the firstViewController and display the "captured photo"**

**FirstviewController**

```
var image:UIImage!


 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


if imageView.image == nil{
  print("nothing")
  imageView.image = UIImage(named: ("defaultPhoto"))
}else if imageView.image == UIImage(named: ("defaultPhoto")) && imageView.image != nil{
  print("have image")
  imageView.removeFromSuperview()
  imageView.image = image
}
}
```

**PreviewViewController**

```
 class PreviewViewController: UIViewController {

  var image: UIImage!

  @IBOutlet weak var photoPic: UIImageView!

  @IBAction func cancelAction(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
  @IBAction func saveAction(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "savePicSegue", sender: nil)
  }
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if segue.identifier == "savePicSegue" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! FirstViewController
        destinationVC.image = self.image
      }

    }
```

Comment: Save your photo on disk, for example, and every time the app opens you take the photo and put it back.

Comment: Without a better explanation, this sounds to me an issue with view and view controller "life cycles". Have you tried updating your images - where needed - in `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: @dfd I have tried but it doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

Update your FirstviewController viewDidLoad logic:

```
if image == nil {
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: ("defaultPhoto"))
} else {
    imageView.image = image
}
```

Comment: I'm tempted to down-vote this answer. The OP stresses *...capture photo and pass it back to the firstViewController...* which clearly **won't** happen in `viewDidLoad`. (On second thought, I am down-voting. How does this answer the *specifics* of the issue?)

Comment: @dfd, look at the prepareForSegue func in PreviewViewController. I see that OP passes needed image to image variable of FirstViewController "destinationVC.image = self.image". So my answer will work if OP uses "presentModaly" segue. Another way this code just need to bring in viewWillAppear func, but not the code which OP uses in viewDidLoad...